# Play local array data though webRTC

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc

I am new in webRTC . As I know WebRTC is use for real time communication . In spec it seems that Stream can be created only by device outout( using GetUserMedia for microphone , camera or chrome tab capture api ) .But in my application i am getting real time Uint8DVideo( eg H264)  data . Can i convert this uint8Data to MediaStream ?

Comment: think so https://code.google.com/p/libjingle/source/browse/trunk/talk/media/webrtc/webrtcvideoframe.cc?r=292&spec=svn292

Answer (score 1):

I assume you don't use getUserMedia, but some arbitrary source.
Getting this video "buffer" to be displayed is tricky and not possible in every browser (only Chrome and soon Firefox). You don't need WebRTC to do that, but something called [Media Source API](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/html-media/raw-file/tip/media-source/media-source.html) AKA MSE (E for extensions).

The API is rather picky on it's accepted byte streams, and will not get any "video data". For H264, it will only except fragmented MP4. more info about that [here](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/html-media/raw-file/tip/media-source/media-source.html#iso).

Comment: Hi Whadar , Media source api has many restriction like first frame should be I frame in media segment . For this application has to wait till next I frame and then it can be used for stream data to play .This approach can not be use for real time data . Second restriction this API buffer data internally untill it get sufficient data to play ( like in chrome no of frame is > 5 ,then chrome start to play)